# angular-cli how to split output js files to vendor and script js file

Tags: angular-cli

I want to split all my angular2, rxjs and other library JavaScript to one file ( vendor.js ) and all my project related files to one file ( script.js ) while building using `ng build` in angular-cli?

I dont not see any where I can mention and split in angular-cli.json

The default angular-cli automatically creates init.js, main.bundle.js and style.bundle.js

Comment: I am still searching answer for it. is it added in CLI yet?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: 1.0.3 didn't, but CLI 1.1.1 is doing this by default now.